# Is there a reason to return null inside parentheses

Tags: c#, .net

I found `return(null)` in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

I wonder is there some reason for this parentheses ? Why not just `return null`?

Comment: (null) is just an expression that returns null, its effectively the same thing.

Comment: The parenthesis is superfluous in this scenario, just like `int x = (1+2);` is the same as `int x = 1+2;`

Comment: FYI, they are not braces, they are parentheses. `{` and `}` are braces.

Comment: @Ashigore, I'm sorry, in my language we got one word for both symbols.

Comment: @Ashigore `{` and `}` are curly braces.  That, along with parenthesis, are two different types of braces, which also includes characters such as `[`.  In certain cultures it's also typical to use the term "braces" when referring to parenthesis.

Comment: @Servy: I've heard that *brackets* can be referred to that way; hadn't heard the same for *braces*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for that, you can just as easily type

```
return null;
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm this was a curious question so I did some browsing.

I found this [post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/456491-whats-reason-use-return-value-parenthesis) which was <del>posted</del> answered by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). He states sometimes it increases readability but has no performance or logical impact.

Another user suggests it is a hold over from long ago when some compilers for C required them.

Interesting to see an example on MSDN with it though, nice find.

[MSDN also has this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sta56yeb.aspx)

> Many programmers use parentheses to enclose the expression argument of the return statement. However, C does not require the parentheses.

Comment: It may also be a leftover of a tool supported refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the expressions `foo` and `(foo)` evaluate to exactly the same thing.  The parens have no effect when the expression only has one term.

I actively prefer *not* using them, though, for a couple of reasons:

- To me, at first glance, `return(null)` resembles a function call just a little too closely.
- They hint at complexity that isn't there, and people -- even people who know better, but are just having a brain fart -- end up asking questions about what's special about that statement.  This very question can be considered evidence.

If you do use them, you should probably stick a space after the `return`.