# C# bracket returned null

Tags: c#, null

Tell me please what is different between

```
return null;
```

and

```
return (null);
```

Sometime i'd seen each an examples

Comment: Some related threads: [Parenthesis surrounding return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161879/) (in C, not C#); [Does using parentheses around return values provide any compiler-related benefits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332928/) (C#); [Is there a reason to return null inside parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146739/) (C#, similar to your question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference in behaviour whatsoever - but the latter is distinctly unidiomatic. I've previously seen it as a sign that the author seems to think that `return` is a function call,  or at least want to treat it as such. (Sometimes there are brackets around *every* return value.)

Just use the first version.

Comment: Maybe that author does not think it is a function call, he just knows that many statements (like `if (...)`, `while (...)`, `switch (...)`, `using (...)` and others, cf. comments to Patrick Hofman's answer) require parenthesis, and then he incorrectly assumes that the `return` statement also requires it. The designers of C# could have decided that the `return` statement required `()`, but they chose not to.

Comment: So actually we can close it as 'by design' :)

Answer (score 6):

The parenthesis serve no purpose.

Those two statements are exactly the same when you look to the actual IL code generated.

According to the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx), the `()` operator serve two purposes:

- Specify casts, or type conversions, like

  ```
  (int)4M;
  ```
- Invoke methods or delegates, like

  ```
  Method();
  ```

Parenthesis are also used to indicate (a group of) conditions conditions, like:

```
if (a && (b || c))
```

Or:

```
switch (a)
```

Or to specify the [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) (deviating from the default):

```
(a + b) * c
```

Lamdba expressions:

```
(x) => { }
```

Etc, etc.

Your code is neither of them, so they are useless.

Comment: actually, there are lot of more uses for parenthesis...

Comment: @vidstige: I will be happy to add them to the list. Can you name them?

Comment: changing away from implicit operator precedence would be an important one; is `a + b * c` the same as `(a + b) * c` or `a + (b * c)`? bundling expressings - `foreach`, `switch`, `catch` etc all use parenthesis

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks. Added it including link to MSDN.

Comment: There are many statements in C# which require (or may take) an expression where the parenthesis `()` is required. For example it is not allowed to say `if condition { Work(); }` or `while condition { Work(); }`. @MarcGravell's example with `switch` is similar. `catch` may or may not specify a type or variable declaration (neither is a usual expression), and the parenthesis is required resp. illegal in the two cases, so `catch FileNotFoundException { HandleError(); }` is bad, as is `catch () { HandleError(); }`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You are right. I think it is the wrong place to make an exhausted list of all uses, but the information might be useful to OP.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Updated the answer so include a few other samples.

Comment: @AleksP: Need more help or clarification?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same difference as between

```
var a = (new A());
```

and

```
var a = new A();
```

namely, no differene at all. The parenthesis is redundant and should be omitted. Some feel it makes the code more coherent with method calls, however the `return` statement is not a function call.